# JointJS Link with same source and target

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

In some cases I have links where source and target are the same element. (same ID).

```
  this.lastLink = this.link.clone().set({
    source: {id: ele1Id},
    target: {id: ele2Id},
    ...
```

It currently looks like this. Links have labels so don't be confused about it. (LINK_TABLE is a link label).

[image]

What I would like to achieve is that whenever source and target are the same, the link should look something like this.

[image]

My initial try was to get the position of target and then increment it for some value.

```
    var targetPositionX = ele2.attributes.position.x;
    var targetPositionY = ele2.attributes.position.y;

    source: {id: ele1Id},
    target: {x: targetPositionX+50, y:targetPositionY+50},
    ...
```

But that try didn't work as I encountered problems while trying to get the target position. If I would console.log(ele2), and then look for position, it would be fine. But If I would console.log(ele2.attributes.position) it would log {x:0, y:0} for some reason. But it's not related to this question.

So what else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding two ports to my element.

```
  var port = {
    id: 'port2',
    position:{
      name: 'right'
    },
    markup: '<rect width="0"  height="1"/>'
  };
  var port2 = {
    id: 'port1',
    position:{
      name: 'right'
    },
    markup: '<rect width="0" height="1"/>'
  };
  ele1Id.addPort(port);
  ele1Id.addPort(port2);
```

After adding the links I had to make sure that I also add ports to my source and target.

```
source: {id: ele1Id.id, port: "port1"},
target: {id: ele2Id.id, port: "port2"}
```

And another thing I added for that 'spinal' link look is this:

```
connector: { name: 'rounded' },
router: { name: 'manhattan' }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an extra vertex to the link. There is a demo for the inspiration: http://resources.jointjs.com/demos/fsa